# Html based on JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am making an API project using openweathermap API, and my problem is I cannot get the name and temperature to change the html of the page. How is the name, and temp in the JSON supposed to be targeted, and put on the page in place of `.city` and `.temperature`? The use of it is to type in a location and returns with the name and the temperature. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//var locname = $('.city');
var temp = $('.temperature');
var APIKEY = '5d2601f4620847da11e653d59d14ae18';
var loc = $('#search').val();
//var responsetext = $(url).html();
function updateByCity(loc){
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 sendRequest(url);
}

/*function sendRequest(url){
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
  if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  locname = data.name;
  temp = data.main.temp;
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}*/

$('.enter').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var temp = $('.temperature');
var loc = $('#search').val();
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 //$('.temperature').html(temp);
 //$('.city').html(locname);
 console.log(url);
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
  console.log("lol");
 var data = $.getJSON(url)
 var datatext = data.responseText;
  var locname = data.name;
  console.log(datatext);
  console.log(url);
  //$(temp).text(data.main.temp);
 $('.city').text(locname);
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

});

});
```

```css
html{
  background-color:dodgerblue;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
}
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.container{
 width:900px;
  height:700px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  left:180px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.citysearch{
  left:375px;
 top:40%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  position: absolute;
  border:solid black;

}

.results{
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 left:300px;
 color:white;
 top:50%;
 background-color:#008B8B;

}
.results:hover{
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

.inputname{
 font-family:Lato;
 position:absolute;
 top:30%;
 left:350px;
}
.enter{
width:100px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
top:265px;
left:250px;
background-color:#00FA9A;
border:#00FA9A;

}

.icons8{
position:relative;
top:650px;

}

.icon{
 position:absolute;
 left:400px;
}
.temperature{
 font-family:Lato;
 margin:5px;
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 right:110px;
}

.city{
font-family:Lato;
margin:5px;
position:absolute;
right:130px;
top:55px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src ="weather.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <body>
    <!-- Partly Cloudy Day icon by Icons8 -->
<img class="icon icons8-Partly-Cloudy-Day" src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="96" height="96">
    <p class="inputname">Look up weather for somewhere.</p>
    <input type="submit" class="enter" value="Enter"><input type="text" name="Button" class="citysearch" id="search">
    <div class="results">
      <div class="temperature">N/A</div>
      <div class="city">N/A</div>
        </div>
    <a href="https://icons8.com" class="icons8">Icon pack by Icons8</a>
    </body>
  </div>
  </html>
```

Comment: Try replacing `temp = data.main.temp;` with `temp.text(data.main.temp);` Does that help any?

Comment: Is it hitting the success callback?try using `$.get()` instead of `$.getJSON()`

Comment: Ok so it now logs everything other than the responseText correctly. I accidentally copy and pasted a not up to date version to here. The thing is response text comes back undefined. So it is not grabbing the JSON correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the snipppet. The url is working, the if statement is working. It just is not getting the JSON and looking for name.

Answer (score 0):

Other than error for unexpected end of input , it works. I figured it out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//var locname = $('.city');
var temp = $('.temperature');
var APIKEY = '5d2601f4620847da11e653d59d14ae18';
var loc = $('#search').val();
//var responsetext = $(url).html();
function updateByCity(loc){
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 sendRequest(url);
}

/*function sendRequest(url){
 var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
  if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  locname = data.name;
  temp = data.main.temp;
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}*/

$('.enter').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var loc = $('#search').val();
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
 //$('.temperature').html(temp);
 //$('.city').html(locname);
 console.log(url);
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + loc + "&APPID=" + APIKEY;
  console.log("lol");
 var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 var datatext = data.id;
 var name = data.name;
  var locname = name;
  var temptext = data.main.temp;
  console.log(temp);
  console.log(url);
  $('.temperature').text(temptext);
 $('.city').text(name);
 };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

});

});
```

```css
html{
  background-color:dodgerblue;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
}
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.container{
 width:900px;
  height:700px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  left:180px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.citysearch{
  left:375px;
 top:40%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  position: absolute;
  border:solid black;

}

.results{
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 left:300px;
 color:white;
 top:50%;
 background-color:#008B8B;

}
.results:hover{
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

.inputname{
 font-family:Lato;
 position:absolute;
 top:30%;
 left:350px;
}
.enter{
width:100px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
top:265px;
left:250px;
background-color:#00FA9A;
border:#00FA9A;

}

.icons8{
position:relative;
top:650px;

}

.icon{
 position:absolute;
 left:400px;
}
.temperature{
 font-family:Lato;
 margin:5px;
 font-size:40px;
 position:absolute;
 right:110px;
}

.city{
font-family:Lato;
margin:5px;
position:absolute;
right:130px;
top:55px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src ="weather.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <body>
    <!-- Partly Cloudy Day icon by Icons8 -->
<img class="icon icons8-Partly-Cloudy-Day" src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="96" height="96">
    <p class="inputname">Look up weather for somewhere.</p>
    <input type="submit" class="enter" value="Enter"><input type="text" name="Button" class="citysearch" id="search">
    <div class="results">
      <div class="temperature">N/A</div>
      <div class="city">N/A</div>
        </div>
    <a href="https://icons8.com" class="icons8">Icon pack by Icons8</a>
    </body>
  </div>
  </html>
```